# yii Database not updating after column added databse manually

Tags: yii

I have added column in database manually in front this showing me the error of no column Property "tablename.name" is not defined.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: you can overwrite model using **gii Automatic Code Generation**

Answer (score 0):

Hi This `error` comes when you created `column` manually and don't add that `column` in related `model`.

Please add that `column` in the `model`. Also if you have no rule for that column than `define` `column` in `rules` as `safe`

```
in your Model
@property string $your_column_name // at this at top with other column names string/integer whatever your datatype is

public function rules() {
// rest of your rules
array('your_column_name', 'safe');
}
```

Comment: thnks for reply but my problme solved by  Yii::app()->db->schema->refresh();